# ¿Configurar .htaccess en Codeigniter Servidor CentOS 7?

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, centos

Cordial Saludo.
Recientemente estoy trabajando con el framework Codeigniter y una pequeña app web,
utilizo CentOS 7 para montar la aplicacion.

El problema radica en que utilizo el helper URL de CodeIgniter para quitar el el index.php de la URL

```
de
http://midominio.com/index.php/miControlador/miFuncion
a
http://midominio.com/MiControlador/MiFuncion
```

Cosa que usando una vieja confiable como lo es XAMPP en local (Windows) funciona con lo siguiente en el .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Pero al montar los archivos al servidor esto ya no funciona, he modificado el .htaccess con muchas variantes encontradas en la web pero aun así no lo consigo.

Error!!

```
http://midominio.com/cod/Welcome/page2
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Hola buenas días, verifica que tenas habilitado en el servidor el **mod_rewrite**. Si mal no re cuerdo es un paquete que se instala.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez en ese caso, no le daría un 404, sino un 503 por la línea `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @Andros ¿no será algún tema de configuración de tu .htaccess? ¿funciona el .htaccess en sí y el server está bien configurado? ¿hay alguna otra directiva en el .htacces que no estés mostrando? E importante, si accedes a `http://midominio.com/index.php/cod/Welcome/page2` funciona?
`

Comment: @Mariano efectivamente, en `http://midominio.com/index.php/cod/Welcome/page2` funciona correctamente pero mi intencion como dije antes es eliminar el `/index.php` con el .htaccess

Comment: @Andros Entendí, pero como yo lo veo bien, estoy intentando descartar otros errores... ¿Seguro que el .htaccess está configurado y funcionando bien? Podrías agregarle alguna redirección de prueba para verificar si la aplica.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregarle un signo de interrogacion antes del primer parametro del index, es decir:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
> ```

a

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente tengo un servidor web con Code Igniter y no tengo el index.php

Te paso mis configuraciones:

**.htaccess**

```
# redirect from root to subdirectory
RedirectMatch ^/$ /directorio/
```

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Creo que esos son los cambios necesarios. Cualquier duda comenta !